# Is "litter" correct on waste bins?

Tags: signage

I threw some rubbish in a litter bin the other day, when it occurred to me that the receptacle couldn't be a litter bin, because *litter* is only unwanted things strewn across the road. Anything in a litter bin couldn't be litter, by reason of it's being in the litter bin.

Am I right, wrong, or just absurdly pedantic?

Comment: At least you didn't decide that you were required to put a collection of puppies in the bin.  :-)

Comment: That's like asking: why do we park in a driveway and drive on a parkway? ;-}

Comment: just put the trash in the trash, and move on.

Comment: Remember the old anarchist rallying cry: **Refuse to be put in bins!**

Comment: Last night in London Airport/ I saw a wooden bin/ labelled UNWANTED LITERATURE / IS TO BE PLACED HEREIN./ So I wrote a poem/ and popped it in. (C Logue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A litter bin is a bin in which you can place what would otherwise become litter.  As such, your objection that the stuff in it is not litter because it is in the bin is at best pedantic; I'd suggest it is at least mildly absurd to be that pedantic over it.

Comment: I think a better word that he was looking for is "rubbish".... you can't rubbish something but you can litter.

Comment: Consider the history.  First there was litter. Someone came up with the idea to place bins around. What to call them? You call them litter bins because that's what you want people to put in them.

Comment: One may also place what was once litter in a litter bin. That makes the waters even less clear -- the bin is there to move the litter into, but once the litter is placed in the bin it is no longer litter. Norman... coördinate...

Answer (score 6):

*Litter* can also refer to a collection of trash.  See definition 4b on [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/litter).

Answer (score 3):

> Am I right, wrong, or just absurdly
>   pedantic?

I'm sure there are other possibilities than the three you list, Brian. But there is nothing wrong with "litter bin" as a term for a trash receptacle. The idea is that this is a place where conscientious people put litter (which presumably they gather up). Once inside the bin, however, one ought to call it trash.

Answer (score 2):

Er, I agree.  It is a rubbish / trash / waste / garbage bin - it may contain erstwhile litter but its contents are the aforementioned synonyms for unwanted detritus.  "Litter" connotes miscellaneous, discarded items laying about and which, once picked up and placed in the bin - become mere rubbish.

The sign on the bin is not an exhortation for how we want people to behave, but a label for what the receptacle CONTAINS.

Comment: But if you put it straight into the bin after unwrapping your sandwich, it never has been and never will be litter...   What have you done to us, Brian?